# Error trash dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, trash, dolphin

Anybody khows how to correct this error in Kubuntu 13.10....? when I tried to erase a file a got the next message --> "A older item named 'trash:/' alredy exists"... This problem I only got it with dolphin whith nautilus I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

I know how to fix this:

- change ownership of your `~/.local/share/Trash/` foledr to yourself. On my system I had the same issue and found out that my `~/.local/share/Trash` folder was owned by root instead of my regular user.

in bash/termnial you could do:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.local/share/Trash
```